# Using expr to extract an IP from a URL

Tags: regex, extract, expr

On, Mac OS X I'm trying to use `expr` to extract an IP address from a URL string.

```
expr tcp://192.168.59.103:2376 : '^\([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\)'
```

This returns an empty string.

Comment: Hint: your string starts with `tcp://`, your regular exression does not.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I realized that expr was looking at the front of the string.  I ended up going with: `echo ${URL:6:14}`